# ':' expected with =! in a if statment

Tags: python

Im trying to use =! to filter out incorrect terms using =! and its giving me the error of ':' expected at the start of the =! . Thoughts? (also the variable is a user input)

```
if usrinp =! rps or 'shoot':
print('Enter Correct Word')
```

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple issues.

1. Checking for inequality is done with `!=` rather than `=!`.
2. Your indentation is off (missing).
3. The string literal `'shoot'` will always be true, so this condition will always be met. Presumably you wanted to check if the user input is neither `rps` nor `'shoot'`. This can be done by checking for its presence in a tuple or list or set.

```
if not usrinp in (rps, 'shoot'):
  print('Enter Correct Word')
```

Without using this approach and checking for equality, you would want to either:

```
if not (usrinp == rps or usrinp == 'shoot'):
  print('Enter Correct Word')
```

or:

```
if usrinp != rps and usrinp != 'shoot':
  print('Enter Correct Word')
```

The `and` in the latter example is required because with `or`, `userinp` could be `'shoot'` and that would presumably satisfy the first check against `rps`.